# Short confirmations like "Good", "Correct", "Yes", "Right" in French

Tags: vocabulaire

If someone is tested e.g. in school, let's say in vocabulary, and the teacher gives a short confirmation after each correct answer like "Good", "Correct", "Yes", "Right", "ok", what would equivalent short confirmations be in French? I am not sure a direct translation would always work, because this is really about everyday-use of the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Words and locutions that can be used in that context, that have been used in the past and that one should still be able to use are the following.

- juste (right), c'est juste (that is right), exact, c'est exact, exactement, correct, oui (yes), c'est ça (that's it), effectivement, en effet, c'est  un fait,

Of course, these terms are not all interchangeable; a presentation of  precise contexts in which to use them would have to rest on  a whole little study. The most simple to use are those below; they express the simple confirmation that something that has been said is right.

- juste, c'est juste, exact, c'est exact, correct, oui, c'est ça,

I wouldn't know about modern terms, that is, to be more precise, terms that have been recently added, let's say in the past forty years. You'll have to wait for more answers to fill that gap.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: ***C'est un fait*** is quite odd in your list. A teacher would unlikely use it in the OP question context. On the other hand, you might also want to add ***bien*** and ***OK***.

Comment: @jlliagre Pour une simple approbation, non, cette locution ne convient pas, mais dans certaines interrogations tout n'est pas simple. Voilà par exemple une possibilité où cette locution a sa place bien qu'une simple approbation puisse aussi convenir. (ne pas s'attarder sur l'authenticité des faits rapportés, ce n'est qu'un exemple) — Comment caractérise-t-on la révolution française?  — C'est un évènement historique dans lequel la bourgeoisie prend le pouvoir à la noblesse. — C'est un fait, mais plus généralement on la considère comme étant une révolution du peuple.

Comment: Precisely, that phrase doesn't match the OP question: "a short confirmation after each correct answer". On the opposite, it shows some sort of disagreement introduced by *mais*.

Comment: @jlliagre True, but notice that this phrase for a "half-correct" answer is not in the second list, which list—I insisted on it—is that of the terms for plain answers.

Comment: Granted. ------

Answer (score 3):

Tel que discuté en [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44024/short-confirmations-like-good-correct-yes-right-in-french#comment89464_44026) :

> [Bien](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bien). [voir II.A.1 : « *Bien! bien, bien! fort bien! très bien!*, etc. marque l'accord, la conclusion, parfois avec une nuance d'impatience. (Quasi-)synon. *bravo! parfait!*] [...] » (TLFi)
>  [OK](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/OK#Fran%C3%A7ais).